# awk passing a variable

Tags: unix, awk, solaris-10

I am struggling with an awk problem in my bash shell script. In the below snippet of code i am passing a variable var_awk for regular expression in awk. The idea is to get lines above a regular expression but the below echo is not displaying any data

```
echo `ls -ltr $date*$f* | /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v reg=$var_awk '/reg/ {print $0}'`
```

I am unable to reg for regex though when i do print reg it is printing but when not doing regex as expected.

```
if [ $GE == "HBCA" ] || [ $GE == "HBUS" ] || [ $GE == "HBEU" ]; then
        for f in `ls -ltr $date*GEN*REVAL*log|grep -v LPD | awk '{split($9,a,"_")}{print a[3]}'`; do
                echo $f
                var_awk="$date"_RESET_CALC_"$f"
                echo $var_awk
                echo `ls -ltr $date*$f* | /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v reg=$var_awk '/reg/ {print $0}'`
```

Comment: Generally, you should use the `$(…)` notation instead of backticks around commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use variable in regex that way. You need to do:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v reg="$var_awk" '$0~reg{ print $0 }'
```

or simply

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v reg="$var_awk" '$0~reg'
```

- Inside `/ /` your variable reg will be used as a literal word.
- Quote your shell variables.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
...whatever you had already..|awk -v reg="$var_awk" '$0~reg'
```

- it is better to wrap shell variable with quotes, e.g. if your var has spaces.
- `/pattern/` in awk is called regex constant. It cannot be used with variable, that's why it is called `constant`. We need to use dynamic regex here in this example.

Comment: Thanks a ton guys. stackoverflow rocks. My problem has been solved. It was nice to know // is for literal not variables.

Comment: @user3341078 Glad your problem was solved. Here at SO you can thank by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.